# C++ project with Bazel and GTest

Tags: c++, googletest, bazel

I want to create a Bazel C++ project with gtest for unit tests.

What is the minimal setup?

(I only have [Bazel](https://bazel.build/) installed on my computer and I am running under Linux)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This is even easier now that googletest provides a BUILD file:

## In [WORKSPACE](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/repo/git.html)

```
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:git.bzl", "git_repository")
git_repository(
    name = "gtest",
    remote = "https://github.com/google/googletest",
    branch = "v1.10.x",
)
```

## In BUILD

```
cc_test (
    name = "hello_test",
    srcs = [
        "hello_test.cc",
    ],
    deps = [
        "@gtest//:gtest",
        "@gtest//:gtest_main" # Only if hello_test.cc has no main()
    ],
)
```

Comment: Thanks! This allows to not have `gmock.BUILD` in the parent directory.

Answer (score 26):

The project structure is:

```
.
├── bin
│   ├── BUILD
│   ├── hello.cpp
├── MyLib
│   ├── BUILD
│   ├── message.hpp
│   ├── message.cpp
│   ├── ... 
├── test
│   ├── BUILD
│   ├── message_test.cpp
│   ├── ... 
├── gmock.BUILD
└── WORKSPACE
```

**Files related to Bazel+GTest**

- **WORKSPACE**

There you download gtest from github:

```
new_git_repository(
    name = "googletest",
    build_file = "gmock.BUILD",
    remote = "https://github.com/google/googletest",
    tag = "release-1.8.0",
)
```

You define a gmock BUILD file defined below:

- **gmock.BUILD**

This BUILD file is in charge of compiling gtest/gmock:

```
cc_library(
      name = "gtest",
      srcs = [
            "googletest/src/gtest-all.cc",
            "googlemock/src/gmock-all.cc",
      ],
      hdrs = glob([
          "**/*.h",
          "googletest/src/*.cc",
          "googlemock/src/*.cc",
      ]),
      includes = [
          "googlemock",
          "googletest",
          "googletest/include",
          "googlemock/include",
      ],
      linkopts = ["-pthread"],
      visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
  )

  cc_library(
      name = "gtest_main",
      srcs = ["googlemock/src/gmock_main.cc"],
      linkopts = ["-pthread"],
      visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
      deps = [":gtest"],
  )
```

- **test/BUILD**

This build file generate the tests:

```
cc_test(
    name = "MyTest",
    srcs = glob(["**/*.cpp"]),
    deps = ["//MyLib:MyLib",
           "@googletest//:gtest_main"],
)
```

The **test/message_test.cpp** file is defined by:

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"

#include "MyLib/message.hpp"

TEST(message_test,content)
{
  EXPECT_EQ(get_message(),"Hello World!");
}
```

And that is all! The other files are defined as usual:

**Files for the supporting example**

- **MyLib/BUILD**

Creates the **libMyLib.so** and **libMyLib.a** libraries.

```
cc_library(
    name="MyLib",
    hdrs=glob(["**/*.hpp"]),
    srcs=glob(["**/*.cpp"]),
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

with a basic **message.hpp**

```
#include <string>

std::string get_message();
```

and **message.cpp**

```
#include "MyLib/message.hpp"

std::string get_message()
{
   return "Hello World!";
}
```

example.

- **bin/BUILD**

Creates the *hello* executable.

```
cc_binary(
    name = "hello",
    srcs = ["hello.cpp"],
    deps = ["//MyLib:MyLib"],
)
```

which is:

```
#include "MyLib/message.hpp"

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::cout << "\n" << get_message() << std::endl;

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Usage:**

- Compiles all targets:

This will also download gtest from its github repo and compile it

```
bazel build ...
```

- Checks the hello target:

You can run it with:

```
bazel run bin:hello
```

- Running your tests using GTest

That was the main point of this note:

```
bazel test ... --test_output=errors
```

You should get something like:

```
INFO: Analysed 3 targets (0 packages loaded).
INFO: Found 2 targets and 1 test target...
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.205s, Critical Path: 0.05s
INFO: Build completed successfully, 2 total actions
//test:MyTest   
PASSED in 0.0s
Executed 1 out of 1 test: 1 test passes.
```

**Reproduce the results**

For your ease I have created a [github repo](https://github.com/vincent-picaud/Bazel_with_GTest) containing this example. I hope it works out of the box.

Comment: If you also need some data files for your tests, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46100906/c-bazel-project-with-a-data-repository describes how to manage that.

Comment: googletest repository contains bazel build file https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/BUILD.bazel Could I somehow provide it to Bazel without explicitly copying the file to my project?

Comment: @MAnyKey That BUILD.bazel is for building gtest. When you use `gtest` as a third party library in your project, all you need is a `git_repository` or `local_repository` rule. Then bazel knows how to compile gtest as a library, so you don't need to explicitly copy the `BUILD` file.

Answer (score 0):

The [current recommended practice](https://bazel.build/docs/external#best-practices) is to use `http_archive` to avoid depending on the system `git` and take advantage of [repository cache](https://bazel.build/docs/build#repository-cache).

### In `WORKSPACE`

```
# 5376968f6948923e2411081fd9372e71a59d8e77 is the commit sha for v1.12.0. 
# Periodically update to the latest to "live at head"
http_archive(
    name = "com_google_googletest",
    sha256 = "199e68f9dff997b30d420bf23cd9a0d3f66bfee4460e2cd95084a2c45ee00f1a",
    strip_prefix = "googletest-5376968f6948923e2411081fd9372e71a59d8e77",
    urls = ["https://github.com/google/googletest/archive/5376968f6948923e2411081fd9372e71a59d8e77.zip"],
)
```

### In `test/BUILD`

```
cc_test(
    name = "test_greet",
    srcs = ["greeting_test.cpp"],
    deps = [
        "//src:greeting",
        "@com_google_googletest//:gtest_main",
    ],
)
```