# C++ Bazel project with a Data repository

Tags: c++, bazel

I have a (basic) C++ project:

```
├── bin
│   ├── BUILD
│   ├── example.cpp
├── data
│   └── someData.txt
└── WORKSPACE
```

where the executable **example.cpp** use some data files from `data/` directory:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::ifstream in("data/someData.txt");

  if (!in)
  {
    std::cerr << "Can not open file!";
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  std::string message;

  if (!(in >> message))
  {
    std::cerr << "Can not read file content!";
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  std::cout << message << std::endl;

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

My Bazel setup is the minimal one:

- **WORKSPACE**: empty file
- **bin/BUILD**: `cc_binary(name = "example",srcs = ["example.cpp"])`
- **data/someData.txt**: contains the `Hello_world!` line

The problem is that Bazel moves all these files in special locations:

```
.
├── bazel-Bazel_with_Data -> ...
├── bazel-bin -> ...
├── bazel-genfiles -> ...
├── bazel-out -> ...
├── bazel-testlogs -> ...
```

In peculiar the **example** executable will not found the **data/someData.txt** file:

```
bazel run bin:example
```

will print:

```
INFO: Analysed target //bin:example (0 packages loaded).
INFO: Found 1 target...
Target //bin:example up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/bin/example
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.101s, Critical Path: 0.00s
INFO: Build completed successfully, 1 total action

INFO: Running command line: bazel-bin/bin/example
Can not open file!ERROR: Non-zero return code '1' from command: Process exited with status 1
```

**The question is how to manage this?**

I want the **example** executable to be able to find the **Data/someData.txt** file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**CAVEAT:** it seems this solution does not work under Windows (see comments).

One must create an extra **BUILD** file in the **data** directory that defines what data files must be exported. The project structure is now:

```
├── bin
│   ├── BUILD
│   ├── example.cpp
├── data
│   ├── BUILD
│   └── someData.txt
└── WORKSPACE
```

This new **data/BUILD** file is:

```
exports_files(["someData.txt"])
```

And the **bin/BUILD** file is modified to add the **someData.txt** dependency:

```
cc_binary(
    name = "example",
    srcs = ["example.cpp"],
    data = ["//data:someData.txt"],
)
```

Now if you run:

```
bazel run bin:example
```

you should get:

```
INFO: Analysed target //bin:example (2 packages loaded).
INFO: Found 1 target...
Target //bin:example up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/bin/example
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.144s, Critical Path: 0.01s
INFO: Build completed successfully, 3 total actions

INFO: Running command line: bazel-bin/bin/example
Hello_world!
```

meaning that the **example** executable has found the **data/someData.txt** file and printed its content.

Also note that you can use the same scheme for **unit testing** with

```
 cc_test(...,data =["//data:someData.txt"], )
```

You can reproduce this note from this [GitHub repo](https://github.com/vincent-picaud/Bazel_with_Data).

Comment: have you just tried to use bazel run in *WINDOWS* to run your example from the GitHub repo?

If you try it, the stream opened in https://github.com/vincent-picaud/Bazel_with_Data/blob/master/bin/example.cpp#L6 will fail.


But bazel running your project in Linux works, though.

Comment: @thinlizzy thanks for the feedback. I have not tested it under Windows. If it does not work, I will update my post.

Comment: @thinlizzy maybe it is just the path "data/someData.txt". I think that windows expects "data\someData.txt". Did you try? (I have no access to Windows, I m only running under Linux)

Comment: that is not the reason for sure. My ugly workaround to make these files to open in Windows via bazel run is to prepend "../../../../../../"s to the file path :(

Comment: @thinlizzy I am sorry to learn that, I will add a comment to my post. I have no way to investigate a problem under windows. Thanks.

Comment: From what I can see, this solution only works with each specific files, but when the rule is more generic, `exports_files(glob(['**']))` - how one can reference this whole group? Leave the path resolution, which is just a black magic for program =(

Answer (score 3):

On Windows try:

```
bazel run --enable_runfiles
```

More details can be found [here](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/8843).

You can add this also to a `.bazelrc` file:

```
build:myconfig --enable_runfiles
```

Build on Windows this way:

```
bazel build --config=myconfig //...
```

Also the runfile lib is an option.

Answer (score 0):

I posted the issue to Bazel issues. It was recommended to use Runfiles to extract the absolute path from the relative path. Then you should be able to plug in the path to `ifstream`. It should be noted that your relative path needs to be prepended by `\__main__`

```
std::unique_ptr<Runfiles> runfiles(Runfiles::Create(argv[0], &error));
std::string path = runfiles->Rlocation("__main__/relative_path");
std::ifstream in(path);
```

See [Documentation](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/master/tools/cpp/runfiles/runfiles_src.h) on Runfiles Usage.

GitHub Issue [here](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/11212#event-3270271775)