# Copy file to the binaries directory using bazel

Tags: c++, bazel

I am building some C++ using bazel.

```
load("//tensorflow:tensorflow.bzl", "tf_cc_binary")

tf_cc_binary(
    name = "model",
    srcs = [
        "model.cc",
        "data_set.h",
        "data_set.cc"
    ],
    deps = [
        "//tensorflow/cc:gradients",
        "//tensorflow/cc:grad_ops",
        "//tensorflow/cc:cc_ops",
        "//tensorflow/cc:client_session",
        "//tensorflow/core:tensorflow"
    ]
)
```

In my C++ code I am doing something like that `ifstream file("file.csv");` if I don't want to put the absolute path of file.csv, I need to copy it next to the binary so that when running, the relative path will work.

I need a way of copying the csv file in the output directory independently of the platform (mac or windows).

Comment: Maybe have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/46100906/2001017 it is the solution I use.

Comment: Thanks! Just putting `data = ["normalized_car_features.csv"]` in the `cc_binary` does the trick. I had to use `system( "pwd > /path/to/log.txt" ) ;` to find out from where the binary was used and the path to the csv file from there.

Comment: Happy it works :)