# C++ - I need a macro or an environment variable to detect when I am doing bazel run on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, bazel

As a workaround, I have to append `"../../../../../../"s` to the file paths I want to open that are part of my data dependencies when I run my executable using bazel on Windows. See also the comment linked here: [C++ Bazel project with a Data repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46100906/c-bazel-project-with-a-data-repository#comment84711653_46100907)

I would like to have something like this below, which would simplify my application testing a lot:

```
auto basePath = "dataDir/subDir/"s;
if( isRunningFromBazelOnWindows() ) basePath = "../../../../../../"s + basePath;
auto file = std::ifstream{basePath + "dataFile"};
...
```

how can I code `isRunningFromBazelOnWindows()`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Bazel now (maybe not yet released in stable bazel?) provides runfiles libraries simplifying access to runfiles. I guess the [design doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/e/2PACX-1vSDIrFnFvEYhKsCMdGdD40wZRBX3m3aZ5HhVj4CtHPmiXKDCxioTUbYsDydjKtFDAzER5eg7OjJWs3V/pub) is best place to start.

Comment: a runfiles lib will definitely help me while I am developing and testing with Bazel, but what about the "release/deploy" version of the product? (which I don't want to use runfiles lib there)